# File.Move or File.Copy from /tmp to /mnt do not work using .NET Core on linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I have an asp .net core app that I'm deploying on Ubuntu linux (in Azure). I experienced a problem when I'm trying to copy a file from the /tmp/ folder to a mounted fileshare. When using linux commands,
`cp /tmp/myfile /mnt/mymount/myfile` 
,everthing works fine.

When trying to use this code,

```
var source="/tmp/myfile";
var destination="/mnt/mymount/myfile";
File.Copy(source,destination);
```

I recieve "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.".
Eventually, I figured out a workaround using this code;

```
var source="/tmp/myfile";
var destination="/mnt/mymount/myfile";
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(source); 
using var fs = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
await fs.WriteAsync(data,0,data.Length);
```

I do not like this solution, but I spent hours trying to find a reason for the exception. Can anybody shed some light?

Comment: what is filePath?

Comment: @stark that was a typo .. in this question, not in my code ;) should be destination